# Postgres: INVALID input syntax for type numeric: "2021-02-14" ... but it's in datetime format?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I'm very confused about this error I'm getting in my Query Tool in PgAdmin. I've been working on this for days, and cannot find a solution to fixing this error when attempting to upload this csv file to my Postgres table.

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type numeric: "2021-02-14"
CONTEXT:  COPY CardData, line 2, column sold_price: "2021-02-14"
SQL state: 22P02
```

Here is my code in the Query Tool that I am running

```
CREATE TABLE Public."CardData"(Title text, Sold_Price decimal, Bids int, Sold_Date date, Card_Link text, Image_Link text)

select * from Public."CardData"

COPY Public."CardData" FROM 'W:\Python_Projects\cardscrapper_project\ebay_api\card_data_test.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER ;
```

Here is a sample from the first row of my csv file.

```
Title,Sold_Date,Sold_Price,Bids,Card_Link,Image_Link
2018 Contenders Optic Sam Darnold #103 Red Rookie #/99 PSA 8 NM-MT AUTO 10,2021-02-14,104.5,26,https://www.ebay.com/itm/2018-Contenders-Optic-Sam-Darnold-103-Red-Rookie-99-PSA-8-NM-MT-AUTO-10/143935698791?hash=item21833c7767%3Ag%3AjewAAOSwNb9gGEvi&LH_Auction=1,https://i.ebayimg.com/thumbs/images/g/jewAAOSwNb9gGEvi/s-l225.jpg
```

The "Sold_Date" column is in the correct datetime format that is easy for Postgres to understand, but the error is calling on the "Sold-Price" column?

I'm very confused. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Notice that the columns are not in the same order in the csv file and in the table.

You would have to specify the proper column order

```
COPY Public."CardData" (Title,Sold_Date,Sold_Price,Bids,Card_Link,Image_Link) 
FROM 'W:\Python_Projects\cardscrapper_project\ebay_api\card_data_test.csv' 
DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER ;
```

Comment: You are a life saver. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have created the table with `sold_price` as the second column, so the `COPY` command will expect a price/number to be the second column in your CSV file.  Your CSV file, however has `sold_date` as the second column, which will lead to the data type mismatch error that you see.

Either you can re-define your `CREATE TABLE` statement with the `sold_date` as second column and `sold_price` as 4th column, or you can specify the column parsing order in your `COPY` statement as `COPY  public."CardData" (<column order>)`

Another option is to open up the CSV file in Excel and re-order the columns and do a `Save As...`